# How do I add a repository Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My output of

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

is

```
deb http:packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu main
```

So I want to replace this as its missing the distribution name.

Searching at https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php I am shown the following:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  main 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  main 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ -security main 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ -security main
```

My question is: How do I replace my malformed repository with the one I found at the repogen website?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323289/how-do-i-add-a-repository-ubuntu-bionic/) by [jrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/41290/jrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-16**:
Is

```
deb http:packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu main
```

a typo? It seems to be missing the `//` between `http:` and `packages.ros.org/..`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-16**:\

> How do I replace my malformed repository with the one I found at the repogen website?

I wouldn 't use repogen for this: it seems to be slightly out-of-date (only lists *Bionic (alpha 2)*), it doesn't help you configure the ROS repositories and seems to be more geared towards setting up the main `sources.list`. For ROS you'd use an add-on file (`ros-latest.list`) which is not part of `sources.list`, but placed in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (which is a directory, not a file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's just a text file, so you can edit it using `nano`, `vim`, `joe`, `gedit`, anything. You will need to use `sudo` though, as it's a file in a non-world-writable location (ie: only `root` may change it).

On my system (ROS Melodic on Ubuntu Bionic) `ros-latest.list` contains:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main
```

Note the `bionic` between `http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu` and `main`.

The following command will write this line to the `ros-latest.list` file:

```
echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/41290/jrock/) on 2019-05-17**:
Excellent. Thank you. This worked.